# LookupRows in lists in marketing cloud

Tags: ssjs, ampscript

Is there any way we can make a lookup in a List in marketing cloud ?
I am working on login where i need data from different lists in SFMC, I can see every list has a uniue LIST ID + The external key. I am unable to find the way to make a lookup in a list.

Please help.

Is there any way we can make a lookup in a List in marketing cloud ?
I am working on login where i need data from different lists in SFMC, I can see every list has a uniue LIST ID + The external key. I am unable to find the way to make a lookup in a list.

Please help.

Comment: In what context?  An email?  A CloudPage?

Comment: If a CloudPage, there are several examples on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com, e.g.: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/220188/5202

Comment: Thanks, @AdamSpriggs
Yes, I am looking for the cloud page.